# I need to identify a component by its marking. SOT-223 package. Markings are N23KBM FE followed by a triangle. Logo hard to tell looks like S

Tags: mosfet, identification

Marking - N23KBM  FE followed by a triangle.

Logo looks like a fancy S.

SOT-223 package

Comment: Please post a photo with a little more board real estate around. "Fancy S" is not precise enough...

Answer (score 1):

Please always attach a picture when requesting a component identification.

Nevertheless I think I guessed what you looking for.

The fancy S is the Siliconix logo.
The triangle (Delta) is the ESD logo. It seems that it is a SOT223 from Vishay (Siliconix).

Here is the marking description of that package :

[Vishay - SOT223 marking](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91369/sot-223.pdf)

In the first line you have the date, assembly and lot codes.
The part number code is in the second line.
So the significant marking here is "FE". I found the following component corresponding to your description **IRFL9014 / SiHFL9014** (depending if you look for a Pb-free or not version), and hereafter its datasheet link :

[IRFL9014 / SiHFL9014 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91195/sihfl901.pdf)

And then a typical picture :

[image: IRFL9014 picture]

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you.